# How to relate partition #X to dev/sdaY?

Tags: partitioning

When installing ubuntu, I get the message:

[image]

But how should I know which is partition #4 from the following (as seen by gparted)?

[image]

I tried `lsblk -o` with different information fields but I couldn't reliably relate any info to `partition #X`.